# Pushing a crate on a friction floor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

A man is pushing a crate at a constant velocity. there is a friction between the floor and the crate of $$\mu =0.41.$$ The pushing force is directed downward at an angle $\theta $ *below* the horizontal. When $\theta $ is greater then a certain value it is not possible to move the crate now matter how large the pushing force is. Find that $\theta$.

Sketching a free-body diagram of the crate I ended up with this eq:
$$\mu m g=F(\cos \theta-\mu \sin \theta)$$
And at this point I looked at the answer to see that the answer is
$$\theta \approx 68 \deg$$
i.e the solution to the term $\cos \theta-\mu \sin \theta=0$.
Why is it so?

Comment: The $\theta$ you have is the limit of $\theta$ when the mass of the crate is zero. So I guess it's the maximum value of $\theta$ for any crate of any mass. For crates with $m > 0$ the value of $\theta$ will be less than this limiting value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You came to the right conclusion, the fact that $\cos \theta-\mu \sin \theta=0$, leads to the following equation

$$\mu m g=F \cdot 0$$

Something multiplied with 0 is always equal to 0. Therefore no matter the size of $F$, the resultant force will always be 0, resulting in no movement.